# The stored password in the db slightly changed through storing process from the original encryption

Tags: delphi, firebird

I use Delphi 10.4 community edition and Firebird embedded database.

The problem: I usually store the login passwords in an 'user' table encrypted. This is the algorithm I usually use (I know it is not the hardest to crack but this software only for myself so who bothers?)

```
function Titkositas(Jelszo: string; Code: LongInt): string;
var
  Ciklus: Byte;
begin
  RandSeed := Code;
  Result := '';
  for Ciklus := 1 to Length(Jelszo) do
    Result := Result + Chr(Ord(Jelszo[Ciklus]) xor Random(256));
end;
```

Once it was encrypted I stored it in the table.

```
procedure TFrmadmin2.BitBtn5Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  s, s2, m, t, dt, most: string;
begin
  s := '';
  s2 := '';
  m := '';
  t := '';    dt:='';  most:='';
  if trim(edit3.Text) = trim(edit4.Text) then
  begin

    if ((edit1.text <> '') and (edit2.text <> '') and (edit3.text <> '') and (edit4.text <> '')) then
    begin
      if (not TDM1.MenuTrans.InTransaction) then
        TDM1.MenuTrans.StartTransaction;
      try
        with insertuser do
        begin
          prepare;
          begin
            ParamByName('NEV').asString := trim(edit1.Text);
            ParamByName('LOGIN').asString := trim(edit2.Text);
            ParamByName('PASSWD').asString := Titkositas(trim(edit4.text), 123456); //this is it!!!
            listbox1.items.add(Titkositas(trim(edit4.text), 123456));
            ParamByName('JOG').AsInteger := strtoint(trim(edit5.Text));
            dt:=DateTimeToStr(now);

            ParamByname('DATUM').Asstring :=dt;
            execproc;
            if TDM1.MenuTrans.InTransaction then TDM1.MenuTrans.CommitRetaining;
....
```

So, it worked perfectly in the past, but now I noticed that the encryption does not function properly (or something else). I have not got a clue what the problem could be:
So this should be the password after encryption: `a÷~D 2¥`
But it is stored in the table: `a÷~D 2Y`
Can you see the slight difference?
It means when I try to log in it does not work because the password I know was changed through the storing process.
I thought it could be because of the character set of the Firebird db I registered. I changed it to Unicode, ISO-1, default but nothing was changed.

I double checked the above code so I printed out the encrypted password in a showmessage which showed proper result and then debugged it from row to row and when it was executed then it still showed the right encrypted characters but then when I checked in the table it was slightly different.

Has anyone got an idea what the problem could be?

Comment: You should store it in a `VARCHAR(..) CHARACTER OCTETS` column so it is stored as binary data, not as textual data, or encode it in hex or base64 and store that. Also, Firebird doesn't have character sets called Unicode or ISO-1. And passwords should generally not be stored encrypted, but using a password hash algorithm like PBKDF2 or bcrypt. Likely some transliteration between character sets somewhere converts that `¥` to a `Y`. In any case, you should post a [mre] including definitions of the database tables.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I wrote I was an amatuer in my original post but someone striked it out from the text. I'll try this bcrypt and I'll get back to you if it works.

Answer (score 2):

XOR-ed string is not a string anymore. It is an array of bytes. You cannot handle it as a string, store as string, etc because for strings the range of valid codes is limited and strings transformations between charsets may be irreversible.